# Pass the current imagestatus of an ImageButton between more Activities, how to?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have 3 Activities, in each of which is the same layout with the same buttons.

- The start button changes after a single click on a stop sign. Now, the stop sign must be transferred to the other pages and remain until you click again.
  (Same with ok sign after click on stop)
- While you see the stop sign, you can switch back and forth between the pages.
- I need some code how to pass the status of the ImageButtons to the other activities, without the status with the stop sign when changing the pages is lost. -> Until you click again.

Codepart for the ImageButton changes:

```
ButtonState btnState = ButtonState.start;
    var button = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.MyImageButton);
    button.Click += (sender, e) => {
        if (btnState == ButtonState.start)
        {
            btnState = ButtonState.stop;

            button.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_pi1);
        }
        else if (btnState == ButtonState.stop)
        {
            btnState = ButtonState.ok;

            button.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_pi2);
        }
        else
        { 
            btnState = ButtonState.start;

        }
    };
```

What I tried:

1)

```
public static ButtonState btnState;
```

here is the problem:

Activity1 click on start appears Stop sign> scroll to Activity2 stop sign is not transferred> scroll back to Activity1 the start sign is back and can not be changed anymore.

2)

```
Navigation.PushAsync
```

is inaccessible from Xamarin.Android

Comment: Looks like just message passing. I think you can use Intents & bundle to share the data within activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pass the current imagestatus of an ImageButton between more Activities, how to?

As Dilmah said, you could use `Intent` to pass your `btnState` between `Activities`, when you open another `Activity`, you could use [intent.PutExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) method to pass the `btnState` value :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
intent.PutExtra("ButtonState", btnState.ToString());
StartActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve the value when the system open the `Activity2` :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout2);
    var clickButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.activity2_button);

    if (Intent != null)
    {
        string nameString = Intent.GetStringExtra("ButtonState");
        if (nameString.Equals("start"))
        {
            btnState = ButtonState.start;
            clickButton.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_pi1);
        }
        else if (nameString.Equals("stop"))
        {
            btnState = ButtonState.stop;
            clickButton.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_pi2);
        }
        else
        {
            btnState = ButtonState.ok;
        }
    }
}
```